# mySql 5.7 Installation Issue on AWS Lightsail Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, mysql-5.7

I am trying to install MySQL 5.7 on AWS Lightsail Amazon Linux, but facing error.
It is latest VM with OS Only ( Linux / Unix blue prints) in Sydney, Zone A. I don't want to use per-installed LAMP with mysql.

I have followed the steps below.

First of all, I have installed the latest updates.

```
sudo yum update -y
```

**Output**

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ec2-net-utils.noarch 0:0.5-3.36.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package ec2-net-utils.noarch 0:0.6-1.1.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package ec2-utils.noarch 0:0.5-3.36.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package ec2-utils.noarch 0:0.6-1.1.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:4.14.165-102.185.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package python27-pip.noarch 0:9.0.3-1.26.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package python27-pip.noarch 0:9.0.3-1.27.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package sudo.x86_64 0:1.8.6p3-29.28.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package sudo.x86_64 0:1.8.6p3-29.29.amzn1 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

When I try to install `mysql` with `yum`, it shows MySQL 5.5 by default

```
============================================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch                       Version                                 Repository                        Size
============================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql                            noarch                     5.5-1.6.amzn1                           amzn-main                        2.7 k
Installing for dependencies:
 mysql-config                     x86_64                     5.5.62-1.23.amzn1                       amzn-updates                      49 k
 mysql55                          x86_64                     5.5.62-1.23.amzn1                       amzn-updates                     7.5 M
 mysql55-libs                     x86_64                     5.5.62-1.23.amzn1                       amzn-updates                     816 k
Transaction Summary
============================================================================================================================================
```

`yum info mysql` shows the `5.5` version

```
sudo yum info mysql

Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Available Packages
Name        : mysql
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 5.5
Release     : 1.6.amzn1
Size        : 2.7 k
Repo        : amzn-main/latest
Summary     : MySQL meta package
URL         : http://www.mysql.com
License     : GPLv2 with exceptions
Description : MySQL is a multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database server. MySQL is a
            : client/server implementation consisting of a server daemon (mysqld)
            : and many different client programs and libraries. The base package
            : contains the standard MySQL client programs and generic MySQL files.
```

---

Then I downloaded and tried to install MySQL 5.7 from rpm.

```
sudo wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm

sudo yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm
```

**Output**

```
Dependencies Resolved

============================================================================================================================================
 Package                                Arch                Version             Repository                                             Size
============================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql57-community-release              noarch              el7-11              /mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch               31 k

Transaction Summary
============================================================================================================================================

Installed:
  mysql57-community-release.noarch 0:el7-11
```

Repo is installed, but when I try to install `mysql-community-server`, it shows dependencies errors.

```
sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

**Output**

```
31 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.29-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.29-1.el7 for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.7.29-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-libs(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 for package: mysql-community-client-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.7.29-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.29-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.7.29-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.29-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have installed *MySQL 5.7* on latest *Linux2 EC2 AMIs* with the same way.

I am connecting the VM via SSH key pair and the VM is not on Static LIVE IP. Please help me and see what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to understand `lightsail` Linux and latest `EC2` Linux difference.
Latest EC2 Linux instance is Linux `AMI2`, while lightsail Linux is Linux `AMI1`.

You may see the difference with below command on both `lightsail` and `EC2`.

**lightsail Linux**

cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

**EC2 Linux**

cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

You may install Mysql 5.7 on latest lightsail Linux with below steps. One of the issue could be that you have to set password through safe mode.
First remove any existing mysql inslatted components (if any).

Then install mysql 5.7 with following steps.

```
sudo yum install mysql57 mysql57-server
```

See pic
[image]

Start the Service

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

Connect with empty password or find temporary password from mysql log.

```
cat /var/log/mysqld.log | grep "temporary password"
```

If it is not connecting with empty password and also if there is no temporary password in mysql log then set the password in Safe Mode.

Here are the steps to set password.

```
sudo service mysqld stop
```

Start without password.

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &


2020-02-08T07:36:00.286533Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
2020-02-08T07:36:00.305112Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

Connect Mysql Shell

```
mysql -uroot

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.7.28 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql>
```

Run below commands in mysql Shell.

```
use mysql;

update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("Pass@123") where User='root';

flush privileges;
exit
```

Now restart the service

```
sudo service mysqld restart

2020-02-08T07:38:51.498523Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
[1]+  Done                    sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Now you may connect with new password.

```
mysql -uroot -pPass@123
```

Remember also set the service to auto-start on reboot.

```
sudo chkconfig mysqld on
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Bajwa, yes it worked. It looks like mysql57 community server edition is not fully compatible with lightsail linux or may be it will work after installing dependencies issue.